# counting integer solutions with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many combinations of non-negative values $x_i$ fulfill

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_L = N$$

if one restricts the sum of any $k$ adjacent variables by an upper limit $n$, e.g.

$x_1 + x_2 +x_3 < n$

$x_2 + x_3 + x_4 < n$

$\ldots$

$x_L + x_1 + x_2 < n$

(we assume periodic boundary conditions)

I failed decoupling the restrictions in order to use a stars&bars method or generating functions. Also, introducing variables $y_i = x_i + x_{i+1} + \ldots + x_{(i+k) mod L}$ decouples the restrictions, but the variables $y_i$ are no longer independent from each other. How to implement such restrictions that couple/correlate the variables $x_i$ ?

Comment: The problem is complicated by nature: you have four parameters $L, N, k, n$. I don't know whether it's reasonable to expect a simple answer.

Comment: I agree, I expect complicated sums that will be evaluated with computers. Yet, I am more interested in how to deal with such Questions, where the variables $x_i$ are connected with each other. The parameters $k$ and $n$ hold for my 'minimal working example' where at least a lot of symmetry is present!

Comment: For small $k$ (e.g. $k = 3$ as in your example) it is easy to calculate the result using dynamic programming. Other than that, I don't have much idea...